# How to list currently running servers that are listening to localhost ports in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, nodemon

I am using VS Code for development. After running the server as usually using `npm start` command (which was set up to run nodemon and the main 'app' file) I closed the terminal.

I thought that when terminal is shut down nodemon get shut down along with the terminal. Evidently this is not so as when I attempt to run `npm start` in the new terminal it throws an error that the port I set up my server to listen to is already in use.

Is it possible to see what servers are running currently and which ports they are listening to?

If there is no such command to list the currently running servers is there any way to shut down the running servers on the local machine without shutting down the laptop I am working on?

By the way everything mentioned above is being done on local machine and no remote server is used. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Linux box you can run this to get the PID of any process running on that port:

Linux:
`netstat -tnlp | grep {{PORT}}`
This will likely find multiple lines since the number of the {{PORT}} value might show up in a PID, IP address, etc., so look through the list to find what you're looking for. The PID and process name will show up on the far right column of the result.

Example for Linux:

```
# netstat -tnlp | grep 443
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14384/nginx: master
```

The column on the right (`14384/nginx: master`) is the PID of that process, and the process name. Once you have the PID you could do a `kill {{PID}}` to kill that process.

The Mac version of `netstat` is different, and doesn't display the PID (at least not that I can tell), and I'm not sure if there's a way to do the same thing on a Windows box.